# Tableau Ranking By Category

Tags: tableau-api

I am doing an analysis in Tableau using their Super Store data set.  I need to create a new column called average sale for each category eg. Avg Furniture, Office Supplies, and Technolgy after that I need another column showing the rank of each category. eg Rank  1.  Furniture, 2. Office Supplies and 3. Technology.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that you can use in your calculated field called... rank - https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_definebasic_runningtotal.html#Rank

There are a few options for rank that you can use, like RANK_UNIQUE, which assigns the same ranking value for the categorical variables that have the same label name. For example, if you had rows where 2 categories were the same, like "Office Supplies" appeared twice, then with RANK_UNIQUE if you were ranking on the sales function, then you'd get a 2 or 3 (or whatever the rank is) appear for both rows

In your context you can likely get away with the standard RANK function:

```
RANK(AVG([Sales]))
```

Let me know if you need anymore assistance

Comment: Rank is a table calc. With table calcs, you also have to specify how to partition the data for ranking purposes, i.e. do you want the rank within the region, or rank within the region per category etc. Read about "partitioning and addressing" in the on-line help. You can specify the partitioning by right clicking on the table calc field and selecting "Edit Table Calc", or (in simple cases), using the "Compute Using" menu option as a shortcut.

Comment: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_definebasic_runningtotal.html#Rank

Comment: How would I calculate the average for the category Furniture, Office Supplies and Technology?  After calculating the average for each category how would I rank in descending order?.